# How to access to object method called "get" on jsp to avoid using scriplets?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, scriptlet

I have following library class:

```
public class LibClass{
    public int get(int a, String b) {
        ....
        return 12;
    }
}
```

How to invoke following method on jsp?

I want to render `12` on jsp.

### P.S.

I have restriction that I cannot use scriplets

Comment: Create your own custom tag,  inside the doStartTag() do the necessary processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [expression language](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjddd/index.html). For ex

Assuming that you've a ${instance} in the scope

```
${instance.get(1,"test")}
```

Comment: No, Suresh is correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780504/jstl-or-jsp-2-0-el-for-getter-with-argument

Comment: it is relevant: **"Passing method arguments in EL is only by EL spec supported in EL 2.2. EL 2.2 is by default shipped in Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2"**

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. You can make a simple Bean which gets this value

```
 public String getDATE(){

 String Date = String.valueOf(new java.util.Date());
  return Date;
 }
```

and then call the above method with the following jsp tag

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="beans.PropertyBean" />
<jsp:getProperty name="now" property="DATE" />
```

you can use anything returned from the bean, In above snippet 'PropertyBean' is the name of my custom bean class. Hope this answers your question.